# Error when specifying a caption when using the plot directive in sphinx

Tags: matplotlib, python-sphinx

When using the plot directive in sphinx, I get the following error:

```
...\docs\source\pyplots/test.py:9: WARNING: Figure caption must be a paragraph or empty comment.

.. figure:: ../../build/html/plot_directive/pyplots/test.png
   :align: center
   :alt: Some Text.


         Some Text.
...docs\source\pyplots/test.py:20: WARNING: Figure caption must be a paragraph or empty comment.

.. figure:: ../../build/html/plot_directive/pyplots/test.*
   :align: center
   :alt: Some Text.


         Some Text.
```

The directive is used as follows:

```
.. plot:: pyplots/test.py
    :align: center
    :alt: Schematics of loading on planar shell structures.
    
    Schematics of loading on planar shell structures.
```

Although my figure is quite complex, this also happens for a very simple `test.py` containing a line plot.

If I don't use any options (`align`, etc.) or don't write a caption, no error is raised. What really throws me off is the added line breaks in the error message. Somehow the figure directive is receiving extra line breaks.

What am I missing? Can I specify both options and a caption?

**Edit**:  The source code in question is [here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/sphinxext/plot_directive.py).

Answer (score 1):

matplotlib sounds similar to how one would use [graphviz with the caption option in Sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/extensions/graphviz.html#directive-option-graphviz-caption).

Maybe try this?

```
.. plot:: pyplots/test.py
    :align: center
    :alt: Schematics of loading on planar shell structures.
    :caption: Schematics of loading on planar shell structures.
```

Although according to the docs for [matplotlib.sphinxext.plot_directive](https://matplotlib.org/api/sphinxext_plot_directive_api.html), you should be able to specify content as the caption.  Maybe using the explicit option name works for you?

Finally the extra line breaks you see in the error message might be clue. I'd check for consistent line endings in the source files.

Comment: Does not work: `unknown option: "caption"` (Sphinx 3.4.3, matplotlib 3.3.3).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Sadly it doesn't work because `:caption:` is not defined in the source code. Please refer to line 231 of the file I added in the edit.

Comment: Checking for the source code, I found out some differences. It seems that the are in fact adding this functionality. Hope it gets here soon. See https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/pull/18426